# Accessing a Date array with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-calendar

I am trying to access an array of dates in TypeScript, something that worked fine in normal JavaScript, but now I am having this error:

`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '0' can't be used to index type 'Date'. Property '0' does not exist on type 'Date'.ts(7053)`

So in React I use `react-calendar` to get an start and an end date, then I use a function to format the array of `Dates`

```
import React from 'react'
import Calendar from 'react-calendar'

export const Main = () => {
 
  const [newDate, setDate] = useState<Date>(new Date())

  const addDate = (date: Date) => {

    setDate(date)

    const formatDate = (input: Date[]) => {
      // Convert month to number
      const getMonthFromString = (mon: string) => {
        return new Date(Date.parse(mon + ' 1, 2012')).getMonth() + 1
      }
  
      const parts = input.toString().split(' ')
      const month = getMonthFromString(parts[1])
      return `${month < 10 ? '0' + month : month}/${parts[2]}/${parts[3]}`
    }

    // It fails here, cannot get 0 index of date array
    console.log(date[0])
  }

  return (
    <Calendar
     showNavigation={true}
     minDate={new Date(2019, 0, 1)}
     selectRange={true}
     value={newDate}
     onChange={addDate}
    />
  )
}
```

When I log the date only I can see it is indeed an Array, before in JS I could just take the 0 and 1 index but not with TypeScript.

```
Array [ Date Tue Feb 01 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time), Date Thu Feb 03 2022 23:59:59 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the first parameter's type to `Date` in your arrow function.

```js
const addDate = (date: Date) => { // ...
```

TS will (rightfully) throw an error when you try to access it as an array.

If an array with one or more dates is being passed you should update the type accordingly.

```js
const addDate = (date: [Date, Date]) => { // ...
```

Comment: What do you mean by `[Date, ...Date[]]`? I don't understand that, also I cannot pass the type as `Date[]` as `react-calendar` requires a `Date` object. Otherwise the `setData` would fail.

Comment: @Álvaro If you set selectRange then your onChange handler is called with two dates in an array. I'll update the parameter type in my answer.

Comment: If I do that I get, `Argument of type '[Date, Date]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Date>'.` on the `setDate(date)`, and if I change the state to `useState<Date[] | Date>` then the calendar just stops working

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with this:

```
import moment from 'moment'
...

const [dates, setDates] = useState<Date>=(new Date())
const [apidates, setApiDates] = useState<ApiProps>({
  startDate: '',
  endDate: ''
})

// Listen for calendar changes
const addDate = (date: Date) => {
  setDate(date)

  const dateArray = date.toString().split(',')

  // Format the date for Google Search Console API YYYY-MM-DD
  setApiDates({
    ...apidates,
    startDate: moment(dateArray[0]).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    endDate: moment(dateArray[1]).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
  })
}
```

So I am using the moment.js library to simplify and by converting the date object to string, all works. TypeScript sees to be happy with an `Array of dates` objects as a single `Date` type.